# ImageMagick: How to create a black rectangle with opacity 40%?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I work on a longer workflow to design elegant maps (project [@Wikiatlas](http://twitter.com/wikiatlas)).

With ImageMagick shell command (`convert`?)...

**How to output a 1200px wide, 1000px high black png image with an opacity of 40% ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at section [*Semi-Transparent Colors*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#color_semitrans) on the *Color Basics and Channels* page of the ImageMagick Examples:

```
convert -size 1200x1000 xc:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)' out.png
```

This uses the `xc` pseudo-format with an [RGBA color](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php#models).