# Create Solid color rectangle with ImageMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick-convert, im4java

I can not find any command to create solid color with rgb options in Java.

I can create it in commandLine like

```
convert -size 100x200 xc:rgb(0,255,255) whatever.jpg
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367622/9719337)

But how do that in Java?

Something like this:

```
        ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
        IMOperation oper = new IMOperation();

        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("xc:(" + color.getRed() + "," + color.getGreen() + "," + color.getBlue() + ")");
        list.add("-size " + width + "x" + height);
        list.add(fillepath);
        oper.addRawArgs(list);

        cmd.run(oper);
```

looks not so pretty

Comment: Is this a question about im4java? http://im4java.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes, about that library

Comment: If you cannot find any equivalent to xc: or canvas:, then you can read in some image and then colorize it. If the image is too large, then crop it before or after colorizing. Sorry I do not know any of the Java APIs for Imagemagick

Comment: It's a web,I should make image depends on parameters which user send to server. I can't make unknown color from uknown image

Comment: With the colorize tool, you provide some color and it makes the image that color everywhere. So it does not matter what image you start with. Just crop any image to the size you want and colorize it with the color you want. This would be one solution if you cannot find the equivalent of xc: or canvas: in your Java API.